# An option is not seeing an argument (that is a variable) in bash, please help?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

```bash
#!/bin/bash

counter=2

while [ $counter -lt 19 ]
do



        username= head -n $counter ./user_sheet.csv | tail -n 1 | cut -d ';' -f1 
        psswd= head -n $counter ./user_sheet.csv | tail -n 1 | cut -d ';' -f2 
        full_name= head -n $counter ./user_sheet.csv | tail -n 1 | cut -d ';' -f3 
        group= head -n $counter ./user_sheet.csv | tail -n 1 | cut -d ';' -f4 
        second_group= head -n $counter ./user_sheet.csv | tail -n 1 | cut -d ';' -f5 

        sudo useradd $username -m -g $group -s /bin/bash -c $full_name

        if [ second_group = LPGestionnaires ]
        then 
                usermod -a -G $second_group $user
        fi

        #echo "$username:$psswd" | chpasswd

        ((counter++))
done
echo Execution complete
```

The part where it says `sudo useradd $username -m -g $group -s /bin/bash -c $full_name` is the part that isn't working, my -g option isn't seeing the variable $group argument as an argument, when I execute my script it returns this: `useradd: group '-s' does not exist`

I'm pulling the data from a .csv file that is located correctly.

If anyone could help that would be great!

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you wanted to assign the result of the `head ...` command to the variable `username` here:

> ```
> username= head -n $counter ./user_sheet.csv | tail -n 1 | cut -d ';' -f1
> ```

That is incorrect syntax. Correct it like this:

```
username=$(head -n $counter ./user_sheet.csv | tail -n 1 | cut -d ';' -f1)
```

And then do the same for the other variables too, which all have the same problem.

Also, change the `sudo useradd` command like this:

```
sudo useradd "$username" -m -g "$group" -s /bin/bash -c "$full_name"
```

Variables used in command line arguments should usually be double-quoted to avoid word splitting.

Answer (score 0):

The final code is this for anyone that is curious:

```
#!/bin/bash

counter=2

while [ $counter -lt 19 ]
do



        username=$(head -n $counter ./user_sheet.csv | tail -n 1 | cut -d ';' -f1)
        psswd=$(head -n $counter ./user_sheet.csv | tail -n 1 | cut -d ';' -f2)
        full_name=$(head -n $counter ./user_sheet.csv | tail -n 1 | cut -d ';' -f3)
        group=$(head -n $counter ./user_sheet.csv | tail -n 1 | cut -d ';' -f4)
        second_group=$(head -n $counter ./user_sheet.csv | tail -n 1 | cut -d ';' -f5)

        sudo useradd "$username" -m -g "$group" -s /bin/bash -c "$full_name"

        if [ "$second_group" = LPGestionnaires ]
        then 
                sudo usermod -a -G LPGestionnaires "$username"
        fi

        echo "$username:$psswd" | sudo chpasswd

        ((counter++))
done
echo Execution complete
```

Comment: You're *almost* re-inventing the `newusers` command here - at the very least, your script could be made somewhat neater by using a `while` loop (something like `while IFS=';' read -r username passwd full_name group second_group; do stuff; done < ./user_sheet.csv`)

Comment: @steeldriver I was just going to say something similar. For getting lines 2-19, I would use a sed command: `done < <(sed -n '2,19 p' ./user_sheet.csv)`

Comment: @steeldriver  my teacher wanted us to write the entire thing so I couldn't use a premade 'newuser' however you are right that it could have been a lot cleaner and that I'm repeating a lot of things